# Definition of profiling in information science

Tags: terminology

According to the [Wikipedia articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(information_science)),

> In information science, profiling refers to the process of
>   construction and application of user profiles generated by
>   computerized data analysis. This involves the use of algorithms or
>   other mathematical techniques that allow the discovery of patterns or
>   correlations in large quantities of data, aggregated in databases.

Although I like this definition, I would like to cite a book or article. Is there a book or article that provides the definition of profiling in information science?

Comment: I don't think you are in the right place, here. Not sure where to send you, but this does not sound like a CS definitionl more one of social sciences.

Comment: People in CS use the *profiling* term for other purposes - and *classification* and *categorization* for what you are talking about